# Java Inheritance calling get method

Tags: java, inheritance, parent

So, I have the Product class and the printer class as follows.

```
public class Product {

public int model;
public String prodType;
public int price;


public Product (int mod, String prodT, int pric) {
    model = mod;
    prodType = prodT;
    price = pric;
}

public void setModel(int model) {
    this.model = model;
}

public int getModel() {
    return model;
}
```

//start of printer class

```
public class Printer extends Product {

private boolean color;
private PrinterType type;

public enum PrinterType {
    inkjet, laser
}

public Printer (boolean c, PrinterType t, int mod, String prodT, int pric) {
    super(mod, prodT, pric);
    setColor(c);
    setType(t);

}

public int getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(int model) {
    this.model = model;
}
```

What is the best way to call the get and set methods? Should I call them from the parent class? Should I even be overloading the method, or is there a better way for me to be setting values? **I do need a method that can be called from the Printer class, at the very least.** I guess I'm primarily asking what best practice is, in a case like that given my one aforementioned constraint.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you overriding these accessor methods?

Comment: There is no need to override the methods of a base class if you are just copying the implementation. Your `Printer` class inherits those methods from the `Product` class already.

Comment: So, I should totally remove them from the child class, and not override them, as the functionality already exists due to inheritance?

Comment: Since you are asking about best practices: You should make the fields in class Product protected if you provide a getter and setter.

Comment: I appreciate that as well, kel, thank you.

Comment: @kel: *"You should make the fields in class Product protected "* ... while this may provide a working solution, this advice could hardly be called a "best practice."  Just like Public fields, Protected fields are part of a class's exported API.  They therefore break encapsulation and the  class's author must support those fields forever, even if the implementation changes.

Comment: @scottb There can be valid cases where fields should be public, private, package visible or protected. One is not generally better or worse than the other, it depends on your use case. But I can find almost no scenario in which it makes sense to have public fields and getters for these fields.

Comment: @kel:  Well, certainly.  Inheritance, itself, breaks encapsulation and there are use cases where protected fields are needed for implementation assistance.  The Java Platform classes have many examples.  However, protected fields become part of a class's exported API just as its public fields and methods do.  The best practice for protected members is to use them only to provide implementation assistance to subclasses (and only when required), which is not the case here.